# Banno Admin API Report Exports

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Within Banno Digital Toolkit Admin API, the reports api seems to only support the retrieval of reports that have been already created. Is there a way to create a report through the Admin API in the same way one can create a report in the Banno.com dashboard (Reports->Create request)? It seems the admin API can only call reports already created and not make new ones on its own. Any clarification on this would be helpful. Thanks

[banno-digital-toolkit]

Currently I have been leveraging the documentation here https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/reports/exports/
I have been unable to find documentation of and api call that can create reports.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the Admin API does not offer a way to create a report.

We'll take this feedback to the Product & Engineering teams.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am assuming it would need to be some sort of post request. I will keep my eyes open for any changes to the documentation.